# New installation of Visual Studio 2017 - looking at my project "using statements" show up as being unnecessary

Tags: visual-studio, episerver

Our IT department had to reinstall my work PC.

After receiving it back, I installed Visual Studio 2017. Added the NuGet Package Sources that I needed as well as installed the EPiServer CMS Extenion for Visual Studio.

I restarted the computer.

However when I launch our EPiServer project in Visual Studio, and look at my code, I see that all the `using EPiServer;` directives show up as being unused as well as are underlined with a red line.

In my code, any reference to code from these `using` directives is also red underlined.

Before the reinstallation of the operating system I had a similar setup of Visual Studio where these `using` statements worked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears all I had to do was build the project once right after setting everything up.

After having built the project, now when I browser the various .cs files, the using statements are showing up correctly as being used where relevant.